How to Prove Convergence of $\prod\limits_{n =1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$?
For $\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z} =\prod\limits_{n =1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$, prove convergence of $\prod\limits_{n =1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
$$f(x):=\ln\left(\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}\right) =\sum\limits_{n =1}^\infty \ln\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right) $$
Applying the root test for the $n$-th term we get  the limit $R:=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\ln\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)} $
$$\ln(R)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(\ln\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)\right)}{n} $$
By L'Hôpital's rule:
$$\ln(R)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n}\frac{\frac{z^2}{n^2}}{\ln\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2 }\right)\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)}$$
As $n \to \infty $, $\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right) \to 1$ and since $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}=-1$
So $\ln(R)=0$ so $R=1$.
But this produnct should converge for every $z$ (Wolfram gives values to all $z:|z|>1$ I tried) So unless I made a mistake (I usually make a lot of small errors and spent hours to find them ) the product only make since when $|z|<1$, If that is true then it could converge for some $|z|=1$ but this is not the problem!

That formula for the "radius of convergence" is for a power series.  But $\sum_{n =1}^\infty \ln\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$ is not a power series.

@GEdgar So the root test won't work ? I Think that the root test works for all $\sum{a_n} $, anyway I will edit the question to be prove convergence for all $z$

The root test will work for the series $\sum\limits_{n =1}^\infty \ln\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$, but since the answer is $1$, the root test fails.  It is not a "radius of convergence".

@GEdgar That one of the worst errors I made in my life! Maybe it is the worst.

The relevant convergence test for infinite series tells us that the product $\prod\limits_{n =1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$ converges  if the series $\sum\frac{-z^2}{n^2}$ converges absolutely.  And that happens for all $z$.

From the Maclaurin series expansion of the logarithm function, we have
$$
\left| \log (1 - w) \right| \le \left| {\log (1 - \left| w \right|)} \right|
$$
provided $\left| w \right| < 1$. By monotonicity,
$$
\frac{{\left| {\log (1 - x)} \right|}}{x} \le \frac{{\left| {\log (1 - 1/4)} \right|}}{{1/4}} < 2
$$
for $0 < x \le \frac{1}{4}$. Let $K$ be any positive constant. Then, we can write
\begin{align*}
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 2K}^\infty  {\log \left( {1 - \frac{{z^2 }}{{n^2 }}} \right)} } \right| &\le \sum\limits_{n = 2K}^\infty  {\left| {\log \left( {1 - \frac{{z^2 }}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right|}  \le \sum\limits_{n = 2K}^\infty  {\left| {\log \bigg( {1 - \frac{{\left| z \right|^2 }}{{n^2 }}} \bigg)} \right|} \\& \le \sum\limits_{n = 2K}^\infty  {2\frac{{\left| z \right|^2 }}{{n^2 }}}  \le 2K^2 \sum\limits_{n = 2K}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  <  + \infty ,
\end{align*}
for $|z|\le K$.

Why the down-vote?

I can only  assume that someone downvotes my question intentionally because I received 4 downvotes on   non active but well received questions this day I also assume that this user downvotes the answers as well

The admins may remove the serial downvotes. Let's see.
